# Importing methods from a Python package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having an issue importing all methods from a file so that I can use it as a package. I have the following:

```
myapp.py
mypackage/
mypackage/__init__.py
mypackage/mypackage.py
```

Inside of `mypackage.py` I have `method1()` and `method2()`. Inside of `myapp.py` I want to do this:

```
import mypackage
mypackage.method1()
```

However this doesn't work. Instead I need to do `mypackage.mypackage.method1()` and I'm not sure what to do to fix that. The only way I found was to delete `__init__.py` and rename `mypackage.py` to `__init__.py` which doesn't seem right.

What do I need to put in the init file to import all methods so I don't have to always type the package name twice?

Comment: Why doesn't that seem right? If you only have two methods in `mypackage`, why not just define them in `__init__.py`? Or even just replace the directory with `mypackage.py` and write them in there; you don't need the overhead of a directory for your module. Alternatively, `import` them into `__init__.py`.

Comment: Well I have a lot more than 2 this is just an example, and in the future I may want to divide them in more files for organization. My question is how do I import them in `__init__.py` so I don't have to specify individual file names? I tried `from . import *` and `import mypackage` but nothing allows me to do `mypackage.method1()`. And I agree no folder would be better, but pypi doesn't seem to support that.

Comment: `from .mypackage import *`? Also: *"in the future I may want to"* suggests you should read up on YAGNI! Start with the simple version, then go complex if and when you discover you *actually need to*.

Comment: Thanks! `from .mypackage import *` did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you have a `mypackage` package (a directory with an `__init__.py`) and a `mypackage` module in that package. You've just posted a strawman example of course, but you risk making import mistakes if you name a module the same as your package. And calling non-package things "package" is certainly confusing!

To get the methods from `mypackage.py` into `mypackage`, you can do package-relative imports in `mypackage/__init__.py`:

```
from .mypackage import method1, method2
```

...or

```
from .mypackage import *
```

The reason you should rename `mypackage.py` to something else is that a small mistake like missing that dot causes the wrong thing to be imported.